How to properly use a variable defined on file level in a task´s `doLast` block with Gradle Kotlin DSL?
Let's say you have variable defined on top file level of build.gradle.ktsscript and want to use it in a doLast block of a task, as in the example below.
What's the right way to do that?
// removing the `private` keyword would fix the problem,
// but isn't `private`something you want here?
private val someValue = "some value";

tasks.register("someTask") {
    // the following line would fix the problem, but I guess that's not the "normal" way
    // val someValue = someValue;

    doLast {
        println(someValue);
    }
}

Error Message: Task :someTask of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask: cannot serialize Gradle script object references as these are not supported with the configuration cache.

Why do you (want to) use private outside of a class?

I'm not much familiar with Kotlin, but I thought private in that context means "file-private" ... and without "private" it would be "public" ... am I completely wrong?

Ok, but even then... is some other file using your build script, i.e., does it even matter?

Actually: no. I just thought using "private" should be the right way here, simular to this example:
https://pl.kotl.in/y3030iRzc
In the example someValue is also used inside of a closure block, but here it's working.
